# Create my own Authenticode root certificate and submit it to Microsoft

Tags: windows, code-signing, ca, authenticode

Scenario: I create my own root certificate for Authenticode (used to sign executable only). Easy. Unfortunately, it will only work on computers where I have installed the certificate!

So, I want to become an official CA (the root certificate will be present on all Windows of the world). As a bonus, I can sell this service to others :)

**TL;DR**: I want to become a official CA recognized by Microsoft for signing executables only (Authenticode, not SSL/TLS).

**Questions**: is it possible to submit its root certificate to Microsoft for they integrate with Windows? What are the costs? Is it possible for an individual and/or small business?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751157.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this useful link! But some users have experimented this in practice?